# Remove specific characters from String List - Python

Tags: python, replace

I have a file from which I read a set of words, this file is "file1.txt".

The content for example of "file1.txt" file is the following:

```
Hello how are you? Very good!
```

What I have to do eliminate those symbolic characters that appear in the example.

For the previous example, the final phrase would be the following:

```
Hello how are you Very good
```

My idea was, once I have read all the words, store them in a list to apply the corresponding "replace" to remove all types of invalid characters.

Another idea that I thought, is when I load the .txt file directly apply the replace there, however after trying different ways I do not apply the deletion of the invalid characters.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys 


def main():

  characters = '!?¿-.:;'
  aux = []

  with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
      for word in line.split():
        aux.append(word)

  for a in aux:
    for character in characters:
      a = a.replace(character,"")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, the first part of my code stores in a list called 'aux' all the words from the txt file.

But I dont know how to apply "replace" method to eliminate the invalid characters from my words.

Comment: you have to work on aux[xxx] directly, or rebuild it using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be implemented much simpler by directly traversing the file and writing its content to a variable with filtering out unwanted characters.

For example, here is the `'file1.txt'` file with the content:

```
Hello how are you? Very good!
```

Then we can do the following:

```
def main():

    characters = '!?¿-.:;'

    with open('file1.txt') as f:
        aux = ''.join(c for c in f.read() if c not in characters)

    # print(aux) # Hello how are you Very good
```

As we see `aux` is the file's content without unwanted chars and it can be easily edited based on the desired output format.

For example, if we want a list of words, we can do this:

```
def main():

    characters = '!?¿-.:;'

    with open('file1.txt') as f:
        aux = ''.join(c for c in f.read() if c not in characters)
        aux = aux.split()

    # print(aux) # ['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'Very', 'good']
```

Comment: Yes is simpler, but I don't know why the solution of your idea gives to me, all the words separated by vowels, for example for "hello" word it gives to me " h" "e" "l" "l" "o"

Comment: @fiticida, `aux` here is just a file's content without undesirable chars. It can be easily edited based on what kind of output you want.

Comment: @fiticida, for example, if you want list of words, just add `aux = aux.split()`

Comment: Like that? aux = aux.split().join(c for c in f.read() if c not in characters). Sorry I am new in python and lists miss me for now

Comment: @fiticida, check the last edit. Also you can implement `split()` in 1 line, but in this case `split()` should be at the end: `aux = ''.join(c for c in f.read() if c not in characters).split()`

Comment: Oh, perfect, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are just reassigning the loop variable, not mutating the list! Change the last loop to:

```
for i in range(len(aux)):
  for character in characters:
    # this actually changes the list element
    aux[i] = aux[i].replace(character, "")
```

You old version was roughly equivalent to:

```
for i in range(len(aux)):
  a = aux[i]
  for character in characters:
    a = a.replace(character, "") 
    # aux[i] is unimpressed ;)
```

Comment: Omg totally true, thanks